# svelte/sapper direct link problems on zeit/now - how to debug or fix?

Tags: svelte, vercel, sapper

In dev, I can direct link to any route. On Zeit/now, I can lead links to some pages but not others. I'm struggling to determine the problem.

Here's an example, navigating straight to "https://partyshoegame.now.sh/games/play/Sparkle" doesn't work, but navigating to the same place from the home page does work.

The Zeit runtime logs don't have any entries.

Maybe it's the pages where I have firebase content?  I use firebase auth via RXJS/RXfire and firestore via google's API.

### Things I assert I've tried:

Link depth: My content is two layers deep. I pulled some up to be just one layer deep, but it did not make a difference.

Slugs: I have the blog sample as well as my content. Blogs work, mine doesn't.

My Helper js code: I had several js files in the routes folder without underscore names. I pondered that maybe those were causing route problems. I added underscores, no difference.

Slugs #2: I placed a named file two levels deep. Can't access it directly No indexes?: some of my routes only have [slug].svelte. I added index.svelte. No difference.

Slugs #3: my files were named [playDocId].svelte and then I used params.playDocId. I switched them to [slug]. no difference

App servers: switched out polka for express. no difference

### the snippet of my routes folder

```
routes
 > blog
  > games
   > play
    [playDocId].svelte
   > edit
     [editDocId]-svelte
```

[screenshot of my routes folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uizJZ.png)

### server response

`
In dev, I can direct link to any route. On Zeit/now, I can lead links to some pages but not others. I'm struggling to determine the problem.

Here's an example, navigating straight to "https://partyshoegame.now.sh/games/play/Sparkle" doesn't work, but navigating to the same place from the home page does work.

The Zeit runtime logs don't have any entries.

Maybe it's the pages where I have firebase content?  I use firebase auth via RXJS/RXfire and firestore via google's API.

### Things I assert I've tried:

Link depth: My content is two layers deep. I pulled some up to be just one layer deep, but it did not make a difference.

Slugs: I have the blog sample as well as my content. Blogs work, mine doesn't.

My Helper js code: I had several js files in the routes folder without underscore names. I pondered that maybe those were causing route problems. I added underscores, no difference.

Slugs #2: I placed a named file two levels deep. Can't access it directly No indexes?: some of my routes only have [slug].svelte. I added index.svelte. No difference.

Slugs #3: my files were named [playDocId].svelte and then I used params.playDocId. I switched them to [slug]. no difference

App servers: switched out polka for express. no difference

### the snippet of my routes folder

```
routes
 > blog
  > games
   > play
    [playDocId].svelte
   > edit
     [editDocId]-svelte
```

[screenshot of my routes folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uizJZ.png)

### server response

`
    The page could not be found.

```
The page could not be found in the application.

404: NOT_FOUND
>Code: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
ID: cle1:mb46h-1573325573258-8bd73af71130
```

`

[screenshot of error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tRuu.png)

---

### package.json

`{
         "name": "partyshoegame",
         "description": "Party Shoe Game",
         "version": "0.0.1",
         "license": "UNLICENSED",
         "scripts": {
             "dev": "sapper dev",
             "build": "sapper build --legacy",
             "export": "sapper export --legacy",
             "zeit": "sapper export --legacy && now --prod && sapper dev",
             "start": "node __sapper__/build",
             "cy:run": "cypress run",
             "cy:open": "cypress open",
             "test": "run-p --race dev cy:run"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@firebase/app": "^0.4.19",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "bulma": "^0.8.0",
        "bulma-extensions": "^6.2.7",
        "compression": "^1.7.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.5.1",
        "date-fns-tz": "^1.0.8",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "firebase": "^7.2.0",
        "firebaseui": "^4.2.0",
        "helmet": "^3.21.2",
        "lazysizes": "^5.1.2",
        "polka": "^1.0.0-next.7",
        "rxfire": "^3.8.7",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
        "sirv": "^0.4.0",
        "uuid": "^3.3.3",
        "uuid-random": "^1.3.0",
        "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "rollup": "^1.12.0",
        "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.0",
        "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
        "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.0.0",
        "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.1",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^4.0.4",
        "sapper": "^0.27.0",
        "svelte": "^3.0.0"
     },
     "main": "main.js",
     "repository": "https://github.com/ketupia/psg-firebase",
     "author": "Ketupia <ketupia@gmail.com>",
     "private": true
    }`

### build process

1. npm run export
2. commit to github
3. zeit/now automatically pulls

   or

"npm run zeit" which is sapper export and push to now.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tRuu.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tRuu.pngThe page could not be found.

The page could not be found in the application.

404: NOT_FOUND

> Code: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
>   ID: cle1:mb46h-1573325573258-8bd73af71130
>   `

[screenshot of error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tRuu.png)

---

### package.json

`{
         "name": "partyshoegame",
         "description": "Party Shoe Game",
         "version": "0.0.1",
         "license": "UNLICENSED",
         "scripts": {
             "dev": "sapper dev",
             "build": "sapper build --legacy",
             "export": "sapper export --legacy",
             "zeit": "sapper export --legacy && now --prod && sapper dev",
             "start": "node __sapper__/build",
             "cy:run": "cypress run",
             "cy:open": "cypress open",
             "test": "run-p --race dev cy:run"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@firebase/app": "^0.4.19",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "bulma": "^0.8.0",
        "bulma-extensions": "^6.2.7",
        "compression": "^1.7.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.5.1",
        "date-fns-tz": "^1.0.8",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "firebase": "^7.2.0",
        "firebaseui": "^4.2.0",
        "helmet": "^3.21.2",
        "lazysizes": "^5.1.2",
        "polka": "^1.0.0-next.7",
        "rxfire": "^3.8.7",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
        "sirv": "^0.4.0",
        "uuid": "^3.3.3",
        "uuid-random": "^1.3.0",
        "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "rollup": "^1.12.0",
        "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.0",
        "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
        "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.0.0",
        "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.1",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^4.0.4",
        "sapper": "^0.27.0",
        "svelte": "^3.0.0"
     },
     "main": "main.js",
     "repository": "https://github.com/ketupia/psg-firebase",
     "author": "Ketupia <ketupia@gmail.com>",
     "private": true
    }`

### build process

1. npm run export
2. commit to github
3. zeit/now automatically pulls

   or

"npm run zeit" which is sapper export and push to now.

Comment: Looks like a build/deploy issue, as apparently the remote site only acts as a Svelte app and not a Sapper one (i.e. no SSR). Could you show your `package.json` contents please? And describe your build/deploy procedure?

Comment: package.json added to question

Comment: Thanks for the addition :) Could it be that zeit/now internally attempts to rebuild from source using `npm run build`? According to https://github.com/zeit/now-examples/tree/master/sapper the change made to the default sapper template is changing the `build` script to run `sapper export` rather than `sapper build` (which is what you're doing in your build process, but I wonder if zeit/now might be overriding that with an internal build).

Comment: My suspicions are around now V1 vs V2.  They switched to functions on the server.  What I don't get is why the blogs work but mine don't.

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue with Netlify.

### A quick summary of the issue:

- Going to the `www.example.com` and then clicking on `/products` takes you to `www.example.com/products`.
- Going directly to `www.example.com/products` results in a 404.

### Solution:

Redirect all URLs to `index.html`.

### Implementation:

**Zeit**: Add a 404 page and redirect that to your `index.html`.

**Netlify**: Add a new file called `_redirects` (no extension) to your Publish directory (found under Deploy settings).
Add this single line to `_redirects`: `/*    /index.html   200`

[From the Netlify docs:](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps)

> This will effectively serve the index.html instead of giving a 404 no matter what URL the browser requests

Comment: great, now my svelte (+ routing) app runs just fine on Netlify. imho they (Netlify) should improve their docs seo, I struggled a lot to find this solution, even though they covered it.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched hosting from Zeit/now to Heroku.  This functionality works perfectly on Heroku.

Comment: @Jaxx: Thanks for thinking about this with me

Comment: You're very welcome, glad you found a work-around. Perhaps you should raise an issue with zeit/now regarding this?

Comment: I had similar issues in Zeit and Netlify. It would be great if we could solve them so Heroku is not the only option

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a special builder to make this happen:

https://github.com/thgh/vercel-sapper